# How to draw a polyline with rounded ends using Google Maps iOS SDK?

Tags: rounding, google-maps-sdk-ios, polyline

I want to draw a polyline in Google Maps SDK for iOS but the ends of the line look pretty ugly to me. Is there a way I could smooth them out or round them off? I tried adding a GMSCircle to the end of the line but the circle gets zoomed in differently than the polyline, ruining the whole effect.

I am sorry but I don't have enough reputation to post images of it yet.

Is there another way I could achieve this whole "rounding-off" effect?

Comment: From the docs, I read Geodesic set to yes should: "When YES, render this polyline edge as a geodesic. Geodesic segments follow the shortest path along the Earth's surface and may appear as curved lines on a map with a Mercator projection. Non-geodesic segments are drawn as straight lines on the map. Defaults to NO." When trying this myself, however, in the GMS iOS component for Xamarin, it did not work. Did you ever find a solution, @Balázs Vincze.

Comment: I think geodesic means how the lines will appear, but the segments of the line will still have square edges. It seems the iOS SDK has no way to change this so far :(

Comment: Really? @Efren 2020 and still no way to change edges so far wtf

Comment: Sadly I think another way 'politics' get in the way of technology, since Google and Apple compete they must not care to develop it. At least they develop the JS SDK that works with cross platform tools, though they are limited compared to native apps and it means you need to port all native to JS :(